# SSRS does not show data in browser but OK in report builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

New to SSRS. I migrated 10 SSRS reports from one server to another.

All configuration remains unchanged. There is one report does not show anything in browser, but is OK in report builder. All other reports show properly in browser.

The original 10 reports on the old server do not have this issue at all.

How do I identify the cause and the way to address it?

I tried to edit this report in the report builder and save it on the server, but it didnt address this problem.

The dataset SQL query works without issue in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons this may happen. Please check the following.

1. The datasource being used by the report, is it the same as the other reports?
2. Execute the query from within report design and see if you get results
3. Connect via SSMS using the same credentials as the datasource and then run the query
4. If all else fails, run a trace on the SQL Server when you run the report from both RB and the browser. You should be able to see the actual query being executed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

So I found what was going on.

The old server is running on WIN 2003, and the new one is WIN 2016.

In the new server there is a default security setting that sets an upper bound of 1000 on the number of valid values that a HTTP form elements may post. The report in the question has one parameter that by defaults selects more than 1000 values. This conflicts resulted in that report wouldn't load on the new server.

The fix is to add a command in the web configuration file that overwrite the 1000 upper bound of the reporting service's appsetting section.

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="some number greater than 1000" />
```

This issue is resolved.